# $sum count of group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Hi there I am trying a simple addition to all my grouped items count. Just cant seem to get it. Atm I have,

```
 return db.aggregate([
    # Match records of type cuisine
    { "$match": { "cuisine": cuisine, "borough": {"$ne": "Missing"} } },
    {   
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$borough",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        } 
    },
    {  
        "$project": {  
            "total": { "$sum": "$count" }
        } 
    },
    {   
        "$project": {
            "total": 1,
            "percentage_of_market": {
                "$concat": [ { "$substr": [ { "$multiply": [ { "$divide": [ "$count", "$value"] }, 100 ] }, 0,4 ] }, "", "%" ]
             }
        }
    },
    {   "$sort": { "percentage_of_market": -1 }},
    {   "$limit" : 50 }
])
```

But this gives me an error

> invalid operator '$sum'.

I have tried multiple ways with no luck. I need to keep the `_id` name also. If someone would care to educate me on the matter would be great thanks.

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention, I would like to keep the original _id, the reason I am finding the total is to get a percentage of the market

Comment: you can't have a `$sum` in a `$project` stage, it has to be part of a `$group` stage, repcae the project stage with `{$group: {_id: null, total: {$sum: "$count"}}}`

Comment: @felix Ahem! [You might want to actually read the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/). Been able to use `$sum` in `$project` since MongoDB 3.2. More to the point of the question for the OP is "what do you 'think' that you are doing in the `$project`?" and what is `"$value"` supposed to be?

Comment: Hey, @felix thanks for the reply. Yes, that works but I would like to group them again. I need the original id name, I am using the total to find the percentage of the market

Comment: @felix That's not the only use. And since it's been out for only a few years now then it's probably time you know.

Comment: @NeilLunn ya it is a bit an awkward one. It is a task I was one of many tasks given as part of a project for UNI.

Comment: @AlexKirwan staying on-topic, please explain what you "think" this is supposed to be doing. Why did you attempt the `$sum` there, and what you expect that to do? You also do not seem to realize you can only reference properties that the previous aggregation stage outputs, as you seem to be trying to reference properties of the original document that you do not name in `$group`.

Comment: @NeilLunn Ya, so apologies for not been so clear. So I was trying to match all restaurants of type ``cuisine `` , then group them from where they are located in the city = ``borough``. Then I must return how many of the restaurants are located in each  ``borough`` as a percentage

Comment: @AlexKirwan looks like you'll need to query to achieve this... The first one to get the total matching ` { "$match": { "cuisine": cuisine, "borough": {"$ne": "Missing"} } }`, and the second to get the marketshare for each value of `borough`

Comment: Ya its a nightmare because she wants it all as one pipeline. Maybe she has not thought this through before given it to us

Comment: Can you post some sample data, the input side as well as the expected output? Also, which version of MongoDB are you using?